# How to use back range in stream API?

Tags: java, java-stream

I want used `IntStream' for executing back range.

So, ordinary `IntStream.range` look like:

```
IntStream.range(1, 10)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

But I need, like this:

```
IntStream.range(10, 1)
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

How to realize it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to calculate the reverse number:

```
IntStream.range(1, 10)
         .map(i -> 10 - i)
         .forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output*

```
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

Remember, `range` is upper-exclusive, so `range(1, 10)` generates the numbers 1-9. I'm assuming here that your `range(10, 1)` should return the *same* numbers, but in descending order, so still "upper"-exclusive, which now means excluding the first value, not the last value.

Answer (score 3):

Check [these](http://www.techiedelight.com/generate-intstream-decreasing-order-java/) examples

```
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

// Generate an IntStream in Decreasing Order in Java
class StreamUtils
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int start = 2;  // inclusive
        int end = 5;    // exclusive

        IntStream.iterate(end - 1, i -> i - 1)
                .limit(end - start)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```